# share variable with views as model

Tags: laravel

i have laravel 5.3 project
im trying to share with all views .. 
so i was trying this .. 
in appserviceproviders 
this is the boot function

```
View::share('path', '/final/public/');
```

ok its working .. 
but what i want to do is share variable with all views like count model records
i mean like this ..

```
$items = Item::get();
View::share('variable',$items);
```

but its not shearing anything . 
so i tried to put it in this class ..

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
private $itemss;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->itemss = Item::get();
        view()->share('itemss', $this->itemss);
    });

}
}
```

and i gat the same error

```
ErrorException in 4f8648bebb04d05a1427fdfec486dd0221e1b875.php line 235:
Undefined variable: itemss (View: 
E:\AppServ\www\final\resources\views\layouts\adminmaster.blade.php) (View: 
E:\AppServ\www\final\resources\views\layouts\adminmaster.blade.php)
```

Comment: you may need to extend the scope of variable with use().

Comment: could you wright the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to extend the scope of variable with `use` keyword.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) use ($itemss) {
        $this->itemss = Item::get();
        view()->share('itemss', $this->itemss);
    });
}
```

From docs:

> A closure encapsulates its scope, meaning that it has no access to the
>   scope in which it is defined or executed. It is, however, possible to
>   inherit variables from the parent scope (where the closure is defined)
>   into the closure with the use keyword

Comment: private $itemss;
 public function __construct()
 {
  $this->middleware(function () use ($itemss) {
   $this->itemss = Item::get();
   view()->share('itemss', $this->itemss);
  });
 } not working